# Ruby code not getting result

Tags: ruby

So heres what I'm using

```
puts "How old are you?"
age = gets
if age == 10 
puts "Yo"
end
```

I expect to see `Yo` if I enter `10`, but don't. I'm fairly new, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, change it to

```
age = gets.to_i
```

[`Kernel#gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) gives a *string*, you need to convert it to *integer* to do the *integer comparisons*. Read [`String#to_i`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-to_i) method too.

Comment: Wouldn't a string be able to take care of a number though?

Comment: No.. they are 2 different object. You need to convert one to other before comparing, if you don't want always `false` to be returned. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are typing a string and expecting it to return an integer

Do this:

```
puts "How old are you?"
age = gets.chomp
if age == "10" 
  puts "Yo"
end
```

Comment: you need to use `chomp` then...

Comment: What is `chomp`? @ArupRakshit

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-chomp